# Need to reverse the entire column

Tags: mysql, sql

The query needs to reverse the name column while keeping the id column the same How can i achieve this?

```
id    name    
2      a     
1      b     
3      c
5      e
4      d
```

To:

```
id    name    
2      d     
1      e     
3      c
5      b
4      a
```

Comment: No. Don't link to images. Write text. Explain the task and tellus what it is that keeps you from solving this yourself. Show how far you have got and explain exactly what the issue is with your solution. This is where we will step in.

Comment: I can't find an answer to this question

Comment: This is difficult. You need two row numberings, one for the names ascending, one for the names descending. Then you can update the table on matching one row number with the other. As this request is closed, I cannot write a answer. You find the statement here instead: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ae028b71c3535dc89abaa516fd38e96

Comment: do you know the answer?

Comment: I just gave you the answer. Click the link.

Comment: I need an answer in sql server 2019 Do you have?

Comment: this code does not work on sql server

Comment: Why do you tag your request with MySQL then? MySQL and SQL Server are different DBMS. Do you need an update by the way? Because only then is the syntax different. For a mere query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6fce02259f8d1023a50d8b4e576a096

Answer (score 0):

As you requested solution in SQL Server version, here it is. This works for most cases.

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (id INT, name NVARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO #t1 VALUES (2,'a'),(1,'b'),(3,'c'),(5,'e'),(4,'d')
;
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn2
    FROM
        #t1)
SELECT
    #t1.id,
    t2.name
FROM
    cte
    INNER JOIN #t1 ON #t1.id = rn1
    INNER JOIN #t1 AS t2 ON t2.id = rn2
```